# i can't run Apache Cassandra on my windows

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have installed Cassandra in windows , i already have jdk 8 and python 2.7
( also 3.8 ) but when i run the commande cassandra in the terminal :

```
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.

  Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'

  on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured

  functionality on this platform.

Starting with legacy startup options

Starting Cassandra Server

Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: it says what to do in the error message: `powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Answer (score 0):

you would need to run the below commands to be able to proceed further - basically setting up execution policy. These are to be run from power shell. Once done, you can run your command from the regular command prompt.

[image]